# Is "D'où vient que..." a common expression?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, questions, emphase

My understanding is that this is translated as "How is it that..." which is an extremely common phrasing in English, but typing this into google does not give any auto-suggest results, leading me to believe I may be wrong about this.

Is it common? If not, how else could I translate "How is it that...", e.g. "How is it that I arrived before you?"

*D'où vient que je suis arrivé avant toi?*

Comment: Phrasing in your exemple is wrong. -S'arriver- means nothing in French, maybe you meant : D'où vient que je suis arrivé avant toi?

Comment: Just a mistake, I don't know why I added *me*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic phrasing is:

> Comment se fait-il que … ?

For some reason the clause is usually in the subjunctive mood. In this case:

> Comment se fait-il que je sois arrivé avant toi ?

It could however be in the indicative, I suppose, when the fact is more important than the reason.

> Comment se fait-il que ces poules ont des dents ?

Comment: Can you also say *Comment est-ce qu'il se fait que...*, or no? And is this to say the phrasing I asked about is invalid?

Comment: It becomes a bit long with *est-ce que*… More informally, “Comment ça se fait que” or just “Pourquoi”. The phrasing you gave in the question sounds quite ok, although slightly tainted. I could well be a phrasing used in some regional dialects.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Or it might be a foreign dialect? Maybe we both have *How come* in mind?

Answer (score 4):

« D'où vient que » était courant autrefois, au moins en français écrit (donc cultivé), mais est désuet. On utilise plutôt « comment se fait-il que » ou tout simplement « pourquoi » lorsqu'il s'agit de poser une question, ou « d'où » ou « c'est pourquoi » au style indirect.

[image: d' où vient que, comment se fait-il]